# How to use USB device instead of DeviceDisplayObjectProvider for cameras?

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive, camera

I have a Fujifilm Finepix HS35 EXR camera.

To have access to photos, saved on its card, I have to use a thing called DeviceDisplayObjectProvider.exe, an unwanted interface, that comes up as soon I connect the camera via USB port.

The question is if there a way to have the camera as a new device letter, as a ordinary pendrive stick, not as Fujifilm Digital Camera (as it appears on File Explorer).
As a Digital Camera, I cannot save other files if they're not a picture or video and other disadvantages.

Comment: Windows 7 64bits here.

Answer (score 0):

Just saw your question so ? looking at my phone plugged in showing on windows tree showing removable disk (F}
If I highlight it I can change it's name. 
Win 7 pro 64
Is that what your looking for? I use the phone for almost all pictures? 
Also if you clk the camera to open it it should give you additional file listings that you could then save to or make more folders.

Comment: Thank you, but your suggestion says nothing. I have no tree of files or removable disk (F or other) when I plug the camera. That is just what I want. Instead, I got that unwanted wizard guiding the download of pictures. I'm looking a way to get rid of that and be able to browse tree of files right on Windows Explorer, through a drive letter, as you do with your phone.

Comment: Forgot to say: yes, I'm on a Windows Seven Ultimate 64 bits.

Comment: Looking at the camera info seems to show the requrement to manage the memory card it  needs the  MyFinePix Stuio
http://www.fujifilm.com/support/digital_cameras/manuals/pdf/index/s/finepix_hs35exr_manual_en.pdf
I was looking around pg 80 and the pdf display is mismatched #s Page 80 of the manual shows page 94 in the pdf menu bar so that's my starting point. And pg 61 for starters.

Comment: Looking at the camera info seems to show the requrement to manage the memory card it  needs the 
http://www.fujifilm.com/support/digital_cameras/manuals/pdf/index/s/finepix_hs35exr_manual_en.pdf
I was looking around pg 80 and the pdf display is mismatched #s so that's my starting point. And pg 61 for starters.
To get it to see and display the pictures in win 7 or any the camera has to talk to the  computer and I think this is the talker.      Call this part one and I'll continue with pt 2 due to the page limitations on this site.

Comment: Pt 2 continued To get it to see and display the pictures in win 7 or any the camera has to talk to the  computer and I think the is the talker. 
I'm thinking your real close to getting what you want.
I'm pasting pg 84 and it should work. Part 3 is comming. this site is making it hard to post the page I made up for you so next up #3
3
Turn the camera on and follow the on-screen 
i
nstructions to copy pictures to the computer.  
To exit without copying pictures, click 
Cancel
.

Comment: Pt#3 3
Turn the camera on and follow the on-screen 
instructions to copy pictures to the computer.  
To exit without copying pictures, click 
Cancel
.
For more information on using the supplied soft-
ware, start the application and select the appropriate option from the 
Help menu 
If you look at say just the memory card plugged into you computer and check it to see is it loaded with file/pictures and  volume of? Or just showing the installation of the below
 .exe program
"DeviceDisplayObjectProvider.exe"
 is a default win7 program. Pt 4 is next

Comment: Pt#4 A little tweaking and I think you can get it working.
the other thing in the Owners Manual  is setting to where you save the pictures, let me go look in the index.
I know I read it some where but don't see it at the moment. my thought is there is either save to memory card or the camera has some memory?
 MyFinePix Stuio
Load that program and give it a try Then you'll be in business.
Wow that was painful.

Comment: " I got that unwanted wizard guiding the download of pictures"

Comment: I'll try again this site page is ? If I try to clk dn a line it enters the comment so I'll not do that.  " I got that unwanted wizard guiding the download of pictures" when that window opens can you scroll  the auto play and see a folder saying open folder to view files using windows explorer? or just the import pictures and videos. If the connection doesn't talk back it would be like nothing at the end of the  usb cord. And after either doing some of the above then it may need to go to admin and firewall settings on enterprise.

Comment: Auto play settings? use autoplay for all media and devices. checked or not. Then go down to pictures/4 choices set to what you want. (mines set to ask me every time) "unwanted wizard guiding the download of pictures"

Comment: I was closing all my misc pages and had this tell all note I copied.          80
Viewing Pictures on a Computer
The supplied software can be used to copy pictures to a computer, where they can be stored, viewed, 
organized, and printed.  Before proceeding, install the software as described below.  
Do not connect the camera to the computer until installation is complete

Comment: Thank you again for your effort to solve the problem.
Yes, I have it and had read the manual and I already know about MyFinePixStudio tool.
Problem is I just want to get rid of this. I just want a single letter on Explorer to browse Memory Card.
And yes, I've already turn AutoPlay on.
Unfortunately, on "Devices" at AutoPlay, it gives me only 2 options:
1 - Open Device Stage
2 - Take no Action
There is no "Open Folders with Windows Explorer" like other medias.
This, you can see [here](http://s24.postimg.org/irr68byur/Finepix_Device_Display_Object_Provider_01.png).

Comment: After turn Camera on, [Wizard shows up](http://s24.postimg.org/bd6ftp2cz/Finepix_Device_Display_Object_Provider_02.png).
Clicking on "Import images and videos", I get this [window](http://s24.postimg.org/th9gec01f/Finepix_Device_Display_Object_Provider_03.png).
And, finally, it starts [importing images](http://s24.postimg.org/e9tgtz86r/Finepix_Device_Display_Object_Provider_04.png).

It's a good Wizard, but I'd like to use Memory Card like an USB stick.

Comment: Don't use gmail as my main and just saw your comments.

Comment: So here is where you  will get to where you want to see the drive. When it gets to the point of auto run display. If you go to the start/computer it will show you the drive removeable disk (? E or F or) and if you clk that it will show as the  dcim or? folder which can then be managed. It is at this point that the drive is then registering on your computer. The talk is the auto run function.

Comment: I put batteries in this old camera to see it and it's a mustek mdc5000 and when i connect it there is no com but when I hit the on button it then shows up as device driver installing then the auto run box opens and then go to the computer and dbl clk the removable drive F shows on the win tree with? gb of data. then if I dbl clk it it opens a explorer file display with dcim folder I hit that dbl clk and get a 100 media folder dbl clk that and there were 2 unnamed imag 0001 .jpg files.  Pretty sure you can now get what you want.

Comment: I was trying to see if I could post a screen shot? not sure if the add comment won't format for that but think I saw it on the ad another answer? not sure cause your pictures were good.

Comment: http://imgur.com/BXkcR9l trying to see if I can get some pictures to post.

Comment: #2 http://imgur.com/ZkXyXng and #3 http://imgur.com/3BkQlvX

Comment: #4 http://imgur.com/5yMrEJa and #5 http://imgur.com/Ygpucu0

Comment: Thank you, Clayzz Photon, but I give up. It's clear that you do not understand the problem and both we're going round in circles. :-)

Comment: Not so much going around in circles but trying to do what may not be possible. This thread gives a good answer to the problem. And me not knowing the specifics of the camera ?. But at least we tried and I always learn from that. http://www.dpreview.com/forums/thread/1504685

Comment: I mean going round in circles because I already said that I do understand all stuff related to Wizard guiding to download pictures, but you come back bringing the same. Nevertless, your last [link](http://dpreview.com/forums/thread/1504685) gave me possible the answer: _"the answer is: you can't. Canon cameras do not support USB Mass Storage Device standards. they will never show up as a hard drive, even with the drivers installed. you have to use a card reader_.